# layout customisation vs using two layouts - expressjs

Tags: html, node.js, express, express-handlebars

Let's say I have one main `layout.handlebars` and a website with two main sections.
Would there be any performance difference if I customized `layout.handlebars` like this:

```
<head>
 <title>{{title}}</title>

 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 {{#if section1}}
 <link href="css/section1.css" rel="stylesheet">
 {{else}}
 <link href="css/section2.css" rel="stylesheet">
 {{/if}}

</head>
```

And rendered like this:

```
router.get('/section1', function(req, res){
    res.render('section1',{title: 'Section 1', section1: true});
});
```

Instead of using two different layouts each for both sections of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No performance hit, but you'll end up with messy code.
What if 'section 3' comes along? Another if?

What about

```
<head>
 <title>{{title}}</title>

 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/section1.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/section{{section}}.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Render it something like:

```
router.get('/section1', function(req, res){
    res.render('section1',{title: 'Section 1', section: "1"});
});
```

or

```
router.get('/section2', function(req, res){
    res.render('section2',{title: 'Section 2', section: "2"});
});
```

Comment: That's a good solution. But what if section 3 comes along and there's more than one css/js file for every section? Wouldn't an `if/else if` statement be faster? Or would it all come down to naming the files properly?

Btw, assuming an `else if` statement exists, since to my knowledge it doesn't.

Comment: Bundle your js / css files. That'd be more of a concern of `be faster` train of thought. Don't forget, these `if / else` blocks and / or my solution are rendered server side - there will literally be nothing in it in terms of performance

Comment: another option would be Partials - http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html